# Unable to Generate Story in Facebook App

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Hi,I am using facebook open graph javascript SDK to publish actions and custom objects. 
Everything runs fine, until a javascript errors occurs in the response.

**Error:**

*"(#100) Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL '' of type 'gourmet-table:recipe' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided."*

The activity log in facebook creates the story , but it does not generate story in the app . Due to which i cannot send it for review purpose to facebook developers so that it is available to all users..

**JS CODE:**

```
FB.api('me/objects/gourmet-table:recipe', 'post', {
                object: {
                    app_id: AppId,
                    type: 'gourmet-table:recipe',
                    url: link,
                    title: title,
                    image: imageUrl
                }

            },
            function(response) {
                var Id = response;
                console.log(response);

                FB.api('me/gourmet-table:read_recipe', 'post', {recipe:Id},
                function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                });
            });
```

You can check the link and debug using any dev tools at

**URL:**

http://gourmettable.in/recipe/gingerbread-cookies/

*In Console you will get the error.*

Your Help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: `type: 'gourmet-table:recipe'` the value `gourmet-table:recipe` is a key value pair or just a single word specifying the type ? if its single word, then i guess you need to escape the colon (`:`) using forward slash

Comment: type:'gourmet-table:recipe' is correct and doesnot need any change i guess because this itself is created by facebook when you click on the get code link of the story from open graph settings.
Other than that..other story with same format for type works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved the problem.. It was a carelessness from my side..Sorry for that

```
FB.api('me/objects/gourmet-table:recipe', 'post', {
                object: {
                    app_id: AppId,
                    type: 'gourmet-table:recipe',
                    url: link,
                    title: title,
                    image: imageUrl
                }

            },
            function(response) {
                //var Id = response; // Error Was Here.. Instead of This
                var Id = response.id; // response.id will return the object id.. I was returning the whole object instead of "id" ..
                console.log(response);

                FB.api('me/gourmet-table:read_recipe', 'post', {recipe:Id},
                function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
                });
            });
```

Sorry for the inconvenience again :)